# Copy specific HTML elements from a webpage to Excel

Tags: html, excel, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to automate a fairly basic copy and paste from a certain website to Excel. To get to the required webpage, I have to select specific items from combo boxes on the webpage. I have managed this part:

```
Sub CopyThat()
Dim IE As Object
Dim htmlButton

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.uvo.gov.sk/evestnik/-/vestnik/search"

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.getElementById("druhOznamenia").Value = "6"
IE.Document.getElementById("druhZakazky").Value = "0"
IE.Document.getElementById("druhPostupu").Value = "0"
IE.Document.getElementById("datumZverejneniaOd").Value = "01.07.2013"
IE.Document.getElementById("datumZverejneniaDo").Value = "30.11.2014"
Set tags = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("Input")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.Type = "submit" And tagx.Value = "H¾adaj" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Now I am trying to look at div classes in the HTML source code and copying all text under a specific class. In this case the code of the data I am looking for looks like this:

```
div class="oznamenie" > <div class="ozn1"> <a href="http://www.uvo.gov.sk/evestnik/-           /vestnik/275652" >28776 - MST</a> <span class="datum">Zverejnené: 28.11.2014 vo VVO 233/2014 </span> </div> <div class="ozn2" title="URBÁRI, s.r.o."> URBÁRI, s.r.o. </div> <div class="ozn3" title="Dodávka technológie pre spoločnosť URBÁRI, s.r.o." > Dodávka technológie pre spoločnosť URBÁRI, s.r.o. </div> </div>
```

I am trying to copy the text from ozn1 into Excel sheet and Cell A2, ozn2 text into B2 and ozn3 text into P2. This is where I got stuck, because I am not sure how to loop through each of the div classes and copy them into those rows. The code should then look at next ozn1 and copy it into A3, B3, P3 etc. The macro should then, after copying all ozn1s, ozn2s and ozn3s on that page, move to next page on the website and do the same.

The second part of this is to open the specific links (in this case http://www.uvo.gov.sk/evestnik/-/vestnik/275652) and copy more text and put in the Excel.

I know there is lot of unfinished stuff and I basically did nothing besides opening the webpage I need, but if you could give me any advice on how to proceed I'd be very grateful.

Thank you in advance for help.